# What are the following numbers?

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence

The number sequence goes like this:

> 3412, 361, 51, 5312, 5342, 531, ......

What are the following *FOUR* numbers in this sequence?

Absolute hint:

> There is no calculations involved.

Hint 2:

> You can't see, what are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each number spells out Braille letters using the number to dot correlation in braille.
>  [image]

And so:

> The five numbers spell P,U,E,R,T,O so you are looking for R,I,C,O to make Puerto Rico the country. Also there is a priority in the numbers. So the numbers are 5312, 42, 41, 531

Comment: I don't know why this question has so few votes it really deserves more in my opinion.

Comment: Perhaps because not many people are familiar with this system ...

Comment: I suspect it's because (a) it's a number sequence and these tend to score low on PSE, (b) the ordering of digits within each number seems pretty arbitrary rather than based on anything recognisably clever, and (c) it was only solved after a very revealing hint was added, when a clever hint word could easily have been concealed in the flavourtext from the start - the path to the solution lies in the hint, not the puzzle body itself.